# Normalization with hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, optimization, database-normalization, redundancy

Do hibernate work with normalized databases? If not, then there comes the lack of redundancy and optimization in the db design. Then how can i achieve optimization in db systems where we use hibernate ?

Comment: Yes, Hibernate works best with normalized databases. Your question is much too unclear and vague to be answered.

Comment: If I have tables with no primary keys or alternate keys then, how can i map tables with classes.

Comment: You can't. Hibernate needs unique, immutable keys identifying rows.

Comment: Well you don't necessarily need a _real_ primary key, but if you want to select and use entities as objects, you definitely need a real identity for rows. If all you do is scalar queries, you should be fine using any column or combination of columns for the id mapping. It doesn't have to be a primary key on the DB.